# MySQL How to make a SELECT SUM from Table and multiplication from other SEARCH?

Tags: mysql

I have this query

```
SELECT ps_ur AS UR, COUNT(ps_ur) AS Value 
FROM patient_services 
GROUP BY UR 
UNION ALL
SELECT eng_ur AS UR, COUNT(eng_ur) AS Value  
FROM engagements 
WHERE LENGTH( eng_ur )>0  
GROUP BY UR
```

Result:

```
UR     Value
002035 3
002400 2
005441 4
...
```

Now I need to calculate from Patient table Male/Female and multiply by the Value

Like this but right

```
SELECT 
SUM( CASE WHEN patient_gender = 'Male' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) Male, 
SUM( CASE WHEN patient_gender = 'Female' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) Female 
FROM patients WHERE patient_ur
```

How to do this?

Comment: What's wrong with your trial? what's that you are trying to get actually?

Comment: @Rahul I don't know how to do search for **patient_ur ** from the first query **UR** and multiply by **Value** and all in one query

Comment: @Rahul I tried this `SELECT SUM( CASE WHEN patient_gender = 'Male' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) Male, SUM( CASE WHEN patient_gender = 'Female' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) Female FROM patients WHERE patient_ur call foreach(
SELECT ps_ur AS UR FROM patient_services UNION ALL SELECT eng_ur FROM engagements AS UR WHERE LENGTH( eng_ur )>0
)` but this bring me only unique results and I need for each

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that case you want wrap the first as inner query. Something like below. Now you can access the `Value` field saying `xxx.Value` and multiply or do whatever processing needed. Not sure where you want to multiply and thus couldn't reflect it in suggested query. Probably that's left as homework for you.

```
SELECT 
SUM( CASE WHEN patient_gender = 'Male' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) Male, 
SUM( CASE WHEN patient_gender = 'Female' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) Female 
FROM patients JOIN (
SELECT ps_ur AS UR, COUNT(ps_ur) AS `Value` 
FROM patient_services 
GROUP BY UR 
UNION ALL
SELECT eng_ur AS UR, COUNT(eng_ur) AS `Value`  
FROM engagements 
WHERE LENGTH( eng_ur )>0  
GROUP BY UR ) xxx ON  patients.patient_ur = xxx.UR
```